# Развернуть приложение Android

Tags: java, android, activity

Подскажите, как системно вывести активити на передний план. Делаю приложение, которое регулярно делает запросы на сервер и при положительном ответе должно оповещать пользователя. Хочется, чтоб при получении положительного результата и активации сигнализации оно само открывалось.

Comment: Вы пробовали просто вызвать `context.startActivity()`?...........